# Debounce only false values in boolean observable

Tags: rx-java

I have a boolean observable that (through a observer) starts and stops an Android service. When true is passed, the service must start immediately. When false is passed, I'd like to debounce it in case a true comes along soon after, to avoid needless (and disruptive) stopping and starting of the service. Is there a composition of standard operators that can do this, or must I write my own, and if so, should I base it on `OperatorDebounceWithTime.java` or is there a simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: You could apply `distinctUntilChanged` before the debouncer.

Comment: I think my answer to this question applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676731/timer-rxjava-control-system-function/30693365#30693365

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want the version of [debounce(Func1)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#debounce(rx.functions.Func1)) that lets you define a custom debounce window for each item emitted. It takes a function that returns an Observable for each item emitted by the source Observable. If the source Observable emits another item before this newly-generated Observable terminates, debounce will suppress the item.

For example, the following code will emit `true` values immediately and will hold on to `false` values for 2 seconds before emitting them. If the source emits another `true` value before the timer expires the `false` will be suppressed.

```
deviceTrigger
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .debounce(startDevice -> startDevice 
               ? Observable.empty() 
               : Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
   .distinctUntilChanged();
```

Note that the `distinctUntilChanged()` calls may not be necessary depending on if your source Observable is already distinct and your consumer handles multiple `true` values in a row.

Comment: Brilliant! I knew about that variant of `debounce()` but didn't realize that the function took each item and could decide on a per-item basis.